# how to extract mono wav from mkv using moviepy?

Tags: python, audio, moviepy

I am using moviepy to extract a wav file like this:

```
ac = AudioFileClip(video_path)
clip = ac.subclip(start_ts, end_ts)
clip.write_audiofile(audio_path)
```

from the API, which part I should tune to make the output mono wav? if it is not possible using this write_audiofile method, is there anyother way to do it? thanks

```
write_audiofile(filename, fps=44100, nbytes=2, buffersize=2000, codec=None, 
                bitrate=None, ffmpeg_params=None, write_logfile=False, 
                verbose=True, progress_bar=True)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `ffmpeg_params` of the `write_audiofile` method allows you to pass additional parameters to `ffmpeg`.

To convert an *X*-channel audio file to mono, you can do `ffmpeg -i stereo.wav -ac 1 mono.wav`.

So, passing `ffmpeg_params=["-ac", "1"]` to `write_audiofile` should do.